# Why does Unicode implement the Turkish I the way it does?

Tags: unicode

Turkish has dotted and dotless *I* as two separate characters, each with their own uppercase and lowercase forms.

```
Uppercase  Lowercase
I U+0049   ı U+0131
İ U+0130   i U+0069
```

Whereas in other languages using the Latin alphabet, we have

```
Uppercase  Lowercase
I U+0049   i U+0069
```

Now, The Unicode Consortium could have implemented this as *six* different characters, each with its own casing rules, but instead decided to use only four, with different casing rules in different locales. This seems rather odd to me. **What was the rationale behind that decision?**

A possible implementation with six different characters:

```
Uppercase  Lowercase
I U+0049   i U+0069
I NEW      ı U+0131
İ U+0130   i NEW
```

Codepoints currently used:

```
U+0049 ‹I› \N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I}
U+0130 ‹İ› \N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE}
U+0131 ‹ı› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I}
U+0069 ‹i› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I}
```

Comment: How is `I U+0049` different from `I NEW`? Is it a different character? Is the English `I` different from the Swedish `I`?

Comment: Asking for "rationale" *usually* doesn't not make an ideal SO question (ie. "Why does C# allow null?") - where such as a documented reason, such should be findable in archives as historic notes, and where there is no such archived information available..

Comment: It is something a programmer would do.  Early Unicode however was put together 30 years ago by people that were typographers first.

Comment: @HansPassant typograhers would complain that the faults in Unicode are due to it being put together 30 years ago by people that were programmers first. Linguists would complain that it was because a bunch of programmers and typograhers thought it up. The multiple disciplines involved would blame it on legacy issues, and in this case at least, be correct.

Comment: @HansPassant but also, the general matter of unification — of saying "this character is the same as that character" or not — is a recurrent one in any attempt at a universal character set, without perfect answers, and neither extremes of splitting or lumping are optimal.

Comment: even if Unicode implements separate code points for those characters, it only solves a problem for Turkish and leaves [a lot of other case mapping problems](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030905-00/?p=42643) as well as introduces some other problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one theoretical and one practical reason.

The theoretical one is that the `i` of most Latin-script alphabets and the `i` of the Turkish and Azerbaijani alphabets are the same, and again the `I` of most Latin-script alphabets and the `I` of the Turkish and Azerbaijani are the same. The alphabets differ in the relationship between those too. One could easily enough argue that they are in fact different (as your proposed encoding treats them) but that's how the Language Commission considered them in defining the alphabet and orthography in the 1920s in Turkey, and Azerbaijani use in the 1990s copied that.

(In contrast, there are Latin-based scripts for which `i` should be considered semantically the same as `i` though never drawn with a dot [just use a different font for differently shaped glyphs], particularly those that date before Carolingian or which derive from one that is, such as how Gaelic script was derived from Insular script. Indeed, it's particularly important never to write Irish in Gaelic script with a dot on the `i` that could be compared with the sí buailte diacritic of the orthography that was used with it. Sadly many fonts attempting this script make not only add a dot, but make the worse orthographical error of making it a stroke and hence confusable with the fada diacritic, which as it could appear on an `i` while the sí buailte could not, and so makes the spelling of words appear wrong. There are probably more "Irish" fonts with this error than without).

The practical reason is that existing Turkish character encodings such as ISO/IEC 8859-9, EBCDIC 1026 and IBM 00857 which had common subsets with either ASCII or EBCDIC already treated `i` and `I` as the same as those in ASCII or EBCDIC (that is to say, those in most Latin script alphabets) and `ı` and `İ` as separate characters which are their case-changed equivalents; exactly as Unicode does now. Compatibility with such scripts requires continuing that practice.

Comment: I totally missed an opportunity to quote a Jimmy Kennedy/Nat Simon lyric while remaining on-topic here.

Comment: Adding to this answer: Encoding two characters that are by design always 100% identical in appearance within the same script would have been a huge security risk. Cross-script homoglyphs at least can be avoided by banning script mixing.

Comment: @RandomGuy32 that's not a good reason to unify two characters that truly are different, though just whether two characters are or not has trickier cases than this (Latin semicolon and Greek question mark, for example, and a great many CJK ideograms). As for the history in question, while homoglyphic characters had known issues even within ASCII or EBCDIC only use, the sort of security issues that arose with greater consumer use of Internetworking weren't as big a concern at the time.

Comment: How are the uppercase I in the Turkish and Azeri alphabets and the uppercase I in every single other Latin-based alphabet “truly different”?

Comment: @RandomGuy32 they're not, but my point was that we can't apply this to all homoglyphs, as we couldn't with e.g. `T` and `Т`, as much as there is a security risk involved.

Comment: The keywords are ‘within the same script’. Characters in different scripts that happen to look the same of course should not be unified.

Comment: @RandomGuy32 `l` and `I` look the same in many renderings (indeed, I and l look pretty identical in the font the textbox I am typing in now is using).

Comment: In some fonts, yes, but you can make any two characters look identical just by applying an appropriate font. Uppercase i and lowercase L unambiguously are two different, non-interchangeable entities. Two separate instances of uppercase i meanwhile would always need to be indistinguishable by design because they are the same letter, just with different case mappings. You can be certain that people would keep using the wrong one by accident or just out of technical necessity.

Answer (score 4):

Another practical reason for that implementation is that doing otherwise would create a great confusion and difficulty for Turkish keyboard layout users.

Imagine it was implemented the way you suggested, and pressing the `ıI` key and the `iİ` key on Turkish keyboards produced Turkish-specific Unicode characters. Then, even though Turkish keyboard layout otherwise includes all ASCII/Basic Latin characters (e.g. `q`, `w`, `x` are on the keyboard even though they are not in the Turkish alphabet), one character would have become impossible to type. So, for example Turkish users wouldn't be able to visit `wikipedia.org`, because what they actually typed would be `w�k�ped�a.org`. Maybe web browsers could implement a workaround specifically for Turkish users, but think of the other use cases and heaps non-localized applications that would become difficult to use. Perhaps Turkish keyboard layout could add an additional key to become ASCII-complete again, so that there are three keys, i.e. `ıI`, `iİ`, `iI`. But it would be a pointless waste of a key in an already crowded layout and would be even more confusing, so Turkish users would need to think which one is appropriate in every context: "I am typing a user name, which tend to expect ASCII characters, so use the `iI` key here", "When creating my password with the i character, did I use the `iI` key or the `iİ` key?"

Due to a myriad of such problems, even if Unicode included Turkish-specific i and I characters, most likely the keyboard layouts would ignore it and continue to use regular ASCII/Basic Latin characters, so the new characters would be completely unused and moot. Except they would still probably occasionally come up in places and create confusion, so it's a good thing that they didn't go that route.

Comment: This is an excellent point which hadn't occurred to me.